# $C(K, K)$ equipped with certain topology compact?

Tags: continuity, compactness

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space, let $C(K)$ be the space of continuous functions $K \rightarrow \mathbb C$ equipped with the norm $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{\infty}$ and let $C(K, K)$ be the space of all continuous functions $K \rightarrow K$. We define a topology on $C(K, K)$ in the following way:

A net $(g_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq C(K, K)$ shall converge to an Element $g \in C(K, K)$ iff $f\circ g_i \rightarrow f\circ g$ in $C(K)$ for every $f \in C(K)$.

As I defined this topology myself my first question is if it is (well-) known or/and has a name. Further I'm wondering if $C(K, K)$ is compact in this topology.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but **if $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb C$** your topology seems to be the same as the topology of $\|\cdot \|_\infty$:

- With $f=id \in C(K)$ convergence for your topology implies converge for $\|\cdot \|_\infty$.
- If $\|g_n-g\|_\infty \to 0$ let $f \in C(K)$. Let us show that $\|f \circ g_n - f\circ g \|_\infty \to 0$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. By *Heine*, as $f$ is continuous on the compact $K$, $f$ is uniformly continuous. So there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. But for $n$ sufficiently large, $\forall x \in K$, $|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\delta$.

So we obtain: for all $\epsilon >0$, for $n$ sufficiently large:
$$\|f \circ g_n - f\circ g \|_\infty < \epsilon$$
i.e $\|f \circ g_n - f\circ g \|_\infty \to 0$.

Comment: You cannot take $f=\mathrm{id}$ because $f\in C(K)$ means that $f\colon K\to \mathbb R$. (I agree that this should be stated more explicitly in the question)

Comment: Indeed sorry for the mistake...

Comment: However, this answer does show that $C(K, K)$ is not compact when $K=[0, 1]$. Please don't delete it.

Comment: I have seen it :-).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that notion of convergence properly defines a topology, but still, I don't expect $C(K, K)$ to be compact.

Indeed, reasoning as in Delta-u's answer, we see that when $K=[0, 1]$ the space $C([0, 1], [0, 1])$ coincides with the unit ball of $C([0,1])$. (By the way, here $C(X)$ denotes the Banach space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$, equipped with the uniform norm). This unit ball is not compact.

It is probably the case that $C(K, K)$ is compact only in the trivial case in which $K$ is a finite set.